# When clicked on a Button, the application is force closed

Tags: android, button, onclick

I am facing an issue with a button onclick. I checked with previously asked questions, but was not able to figure out the problem, where exactly it lies. The first time, when I click on, 'Next' button, it successfully moves to next page, but in the second page, after entering details, when the 'Proceed'button is clicked, the application crashes.

Activity1:

```
package com.application.P1;

//import com.application.P1.R;
//import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class P1Activity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */



    //  @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //Using TextView to Give a Home Page Screen
            TextView tv=new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("WELCOME TO Application Click on Next to Proceed");



             setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }





        public void Welcome( View v){

           // Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your Nickname and proceed further", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        


            Intent myActivity = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
            startActivity(myActivity);

          //  EditText t



        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }



    }
```

Activity2:

```
package com.application.P1;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Activity2 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      //  @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



             setContentView(R.layout.login);
        }



        public void Proceed4( View v){

    //      Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks for entering your nickname", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           Intent myActivity2 = new Intent(this,Activity3.class);
            startActivity(myActivity2);



          //  EditText t



        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



    }
```

Activity3:

```
package com.application.P1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
//import android.content.Intent;
//import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Activity3 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    //  @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



             setContentView(R.layout.check);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }







    }
```

All the three activities are in same package. In the second activity, after button click, when a message is toasted, the toasted message is coming properly. But, when the next activity is called, it is not coming.

```
XML Coding:
```

Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
      android:text="@string/Next"
      android:id="@+id/Button01" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
      android:onClick="Welcome"/>





</LinearLayout>
```

login.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >



     <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mynickname" />



 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mynickname3"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <Button
      android:text="@string/Proceed"
      android:id="@+id/Button02" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
      android:onClick="Proceed4"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Check.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello3" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.application.P1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/cherry"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".P1Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity2">


        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity3"></activity>

        </application>

</manifest>
```

03-22 00:50:27.125: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 00:50:27.125: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-22 00:50:27.125: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
03-22 00:50:27.125: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  ... 11 more
03-22 00:50:27.125: E/AndroidRuntime(857): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity

```
class {com.application.P1/com.application.P1.Activity3}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-22 00:50:27.125: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
03-22 00:50:27.125: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
03-22 00:50:27.125: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
03-22 00:50:27.125: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
03-22 00:50:27.125: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at com.application.P1.Activity2.Proceed4(Activity2.java:31)
03-22 00:50:27.125: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  ... 14 more
03-22 00:50:29.867: I/Process(857): Sending signal. PID: 857 SIG: 9
```

Values.xml:

```
<string name="hello">Welcome to Expresso Application</string>
      <string name="Next">Next</string>
      <string name="app_name">Expresso2</string>
      <string name="Proceed">Proceed</string>
      <string name="Nickname">Nickname</string>
      <string name="mynickname">myNickname</string>

       <string name="hello3">Tensions</string>
```

Comment: Please post the and stack trace exception from logcat. (If there are several chained together with "Caused by...", post the last stack trace.)

Comment: Thanks! That helps...I am attaching the last stack trace...

Comment: Hi @TedHopp, looking forward for an answer from your side...Has the last set of stacktrace added in the Question, thrown any light on the problem??

Comment: no...the problem is present...Here, I have changed the name of the activity manually to refer easily..Otherwise, the name of the activity is same everywhere...

Comment: When I toast the message, after clicking on button, 'Proceed', the toast message is coming. But, when I call a new activity Intent, the application is force closing...

Comment: It's complaining that have not declared Activity3 in the manifest. Have you checked this?

Comment: @TedHopp, thanks...That was a mistake from my side, w.r.t the naming of the Class...The class name was 'QuestionsAsked' and 'the naming in Manifest file was, 'Questions'...aka, 'Activity3'. Plz. point out this mistake and post as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the stack trace, it appears that your manifest file does not declare the activity. Check that there is an `<activity>` tag for `Activity3`.

Answer (score 0):

fist replace in Activity A:
this

```
//  @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //Using TextView to Give a Home Page Screen
            TextView tv=new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("WELCOME TO Application Click on Next to Proceed");



             setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
```

from this code :

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
            //Using TextView to Give a Home Page Screen
            TextView tv=new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("WELCOME TO Application Click on Next to Proceed");

        }
```

Comment: Ok...I have done the changes...:)(Guess, it is for proper formatting, thanks btw for that..)But, still the problem is unsolved...!!

Comment: tell me package name of activity2 and Activity3

Comment: just  clean your project from Project->Clean in eclipse

Comment: you have `Expresso2Activity` instead of `P1Activity `

Comment: no, for convenience sake, I had put, the name here as, 'P1Activity'...In the code, both are same...I will edit...